# ¿ Cómo reutilizar una función de javascript en varios div (html) , que se crean con infinite scroll?

Tags: javascript, php, html, while, scroll

tengo un dilema, he logrado después de varios tutoriales, crear un infinite scroll que me va formando un árbol de ´DIV' ( esto lo hice con JavaScript). Pero a algunos de esos DIV, les agrego datos ($variables) con PHP que obtengo de un query mediante un bucle while.

Pero tengo dos grandes problemas. El primero es que la variable que puedo agregar es siempre la misma (la ultima del ciclo while) intente cambiar el lugar de cierre del bucle pero no funciona.

El otro problema, es que mediante la función de JavaScript que utilizo para agregar la variable ocupando el id del DIV, siempre me agrega la misma variable en el primero DIV, creado por el infinite scroll, y no en los siguientes.

Quiero lograr dos cosas, por un lado agregar en estos distintos DIV que se van creando las variables que voy obteniendo del while y que estas variables sean diferentes en cada DIV ( se tratan de imágenes de portadas de diferentes libros).

Había pensado en un bucle FOR y en un array para ordenar mediante un n=0 que fuera incrementando con n++ los datos. pero no se como redactar la orden. si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería muchisimo.  Les dejo mi codigo :

```
<div class="peliculas-aventurasAC contenedor">
<div class="contenedor-titulo-controles-aventurasAC">
    <h3>ebooks De Ciencia Ficcion</h3>
    <div class="indicadores-aventurasAC"></div>
</div>
<div class="contenedor-principal-aventurasAC">
    <button title="#" text="#"role="button" id="flecha-izquierda-aventurasAC" class="flecha-izquierda-aventurasAC"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></button>
    <div class="contenedor-carousel-aventurasAC">
        <div class="carousel-aventurasAC">
            <div class="pelicula-aventurasACp" >
<?php

                $conexion=conexion();
                $query=listarCF($conexion);
                while($datos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $id=$datos['id'];
                    $portada=$datos['portada'];
                    $user=$datos['user'];
                    $categoriaP=$datos['categoriaP'];
                    $serie=$datos['serie'];
                    


                $valorP="";
                if($categoriaP=='jpg' || $categoriaP=='png'){
                    $valorP="<img width='50' src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($portada)."'>";
                }

                if($categoriaP=='pdf'){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='../login/img/pdf.png'>";
                }

                if($categoriaP=='xls' || $categoriaP=='xlsm' ){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='../login/img/excel.png'>";
                }

                if($categoriaP=='doc' || $categoriaP=='docx'){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='../login/img/word.png'>";
                }
                if($categoriaP=='mp4'){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='../login/img/pelicula.png'>";
                }

                if($categoriaP=='mp3'){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='../login/img/musica.png'>";
                }

                if($valorP==''){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='img/desconocido.png'>";
                }                                               
?>
                
            </div>
            <div class="pelicula-aventurasAC">
            <td><a class="portada" include="../vista/cargar/cargar_ciencia_ficcion_P.php? $id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $valorP ;?></td>
            <div class="card-aventurasAC">
                        <div class="card-content-aventurasAC">
                        <div class="card-title-aventurasAC"><td><?php echo $serie  ;?> </div>
                            <form method="POST" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" action="../ebooks/buscador/universal/universal_ciencia_ficcion.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
                            <input style="opacity: 0;" type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar"  class="serie" value = "<?php echo $serie; ?>">
                            <input class="enviar" type="submit" style="z-index: 2"  name="enviar" id="busqueda" value="Ver">
                            </form>     
                </a>    
                        </div>  
                        </div>
            <?php  }  ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
    <button title="#" text="#" role="button" id="flecha-derecha-aventurasAC" class="flecha-derecha-aventurasAC"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button>
</div>      
</div>


<script>
        
        var oset = 0;
        var iload = 1;
        var holdload = false;


        $(function(){
            loadArt(1);
        });

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()-$(window).height()-350){
                loadArt(1);
                agregarImg();
            }
            })
        

        function loadArt(a){
           
        if(!holdload){
            var holder = {oset:oset, iload:a};
       
            holdload = true;
            $.ajax({
                url:"api1.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:holder,
                dataType:"json",
                success: function (data){
                   
                    for(var i=0;i<data.nombre.length;i++){
                        oset++;
                        var item = data.nombre[i];
                        var html = '<div class="box">'+item.id+'/'+item.nombre+'/'+item.tipo+'/'+item.user+'</div>';
                        $('#content').append(html);

                        console.log(item)


                        var html1 = document.createElement("div");
                        html1.className="peliculas-recomendadas contenedor";
                        html1.id="peliculas-recomendadas";
                        

                        var html2 = document.createElement("div");
                        html2.className="contenedor-titulo-controles";

                        var html3 = document.createElement("h3");
                        html3.innerText = 'ebooks De Accion';
                        
                        var html4 = document.createElement("div");
                        html4.className="indicadores";

                        var html5 = document.createElement("div");
                        html5.className="contenedor-principal";

 let buttoniz = document.createElement('button');
  html5.appendChild(buttoniz);  
  
  buttoniz.className="flecha-izquierda";
  buttoniz.id = `flecha-izquierda`;
  buttoniz.title="<" ;
  buttoniz.text="#";
  buttoniz.role="button";
  buttoniz.type="button";

let iz = document.createElement('i');
buttoniz.appendChild(iz); 

iz.className="fas fa-angle-left";

                    var html6 = document.createElement("div");
                        html6.className="contenedor-carousel";

                    var html7 = document.createElement("div");
                        html7.className="carousel";

                    var html8 = document.createElement("div");
                        html8.className="peliculaP";
                        html8.id="peliculaP";


                    var html9 = document.createElement("div");
                        html9.className="pelicula";
                        html9.id="pelicula";
                        

                        

let td = document.createElement('td');
html9.appendChild(td);  
  
  td.className="portada";
  td.id = `portada`;
  
            
  var html66 =  '<td <a class="portada" include="../vista/cargar/cargar_ciencia_ficcion_P.php? $id=<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>';
                        $('#portada').append(html66);


                    var html10 = document.createElement("div");
                        html10.className="card";
                        html10.id = `card`;

                    var html11 = document.createElement("div");
                        html11.className="card-content";    

                    var html12 = document.createElement("div");
                        html12.className="card-title";

let form = document.createElement('form');
html12.appendChild(form);  

form.method="POST" ;
form.name="busqueda" ;
form.id="busqueda" ;
form.action="../ebooks/buscador/universal/universal_accion.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>";

let input = document.createElement('input');
form.appendChild(input); 

input.style="opacity: 0";
input.type="text";
input.name="busqueda";
input.id="busqueda";
input.placeholder="Buscar" ;
input.class="serie" ;
input.value = "";

let input1 = document.createElement('input');
form.appendChild(input1); 

input1.class="enviar";
input1.type="submit";
input1.style="z-index: 2"; 
input1.name="enviar";
input1.id="busqueda";
input1.value="Ver";

let buttond = document.createElement('button');
  html5.appendChild(buttond);  
  
  buttond.className="flecha-derecha";
  buttond.id = `flecha-derecha`;
  buttond.title=">" ;
  buttond.text="#";
  buttond.role="button";
  buttond.type="button";

  let id = document.createElement('i');
buttoniz.appendChild(id); 

id.className="fas fa-angle-right";

                        body.appendChild(html1);
                        html1.appendChild(html2);
                        html2.appendChild(html3);
                        html2.appendChild(html4);
                        html1.appendChild(html5);
                        html5.appendChild(html6);
                        html6.appendChild(html7);
                        html7.appendChild(html8);
                        html7.appendChild(html9);
                        html7.appendChild(html10);
                        html10.appendChild(html11);
                        html11.appendChild(html12);

                          console.log(html1)
                          

                    }

                    holdload = false;
                    if(data.nombre.length == 0){
                        holdload = true;
                    }
                
                }
            })
        }
    }
<?php
    $conexion=conexion();
                $query=listarCF($conexion);
                $contador=0;
                while($datos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $contador++;
                    $id=$datos['id'];
                    $portada=$datos['portada'];
                    $user=$datos['user'];
                    $categoriaP=$datos['categoriaP'];
                    $serie=$datos['serie'];
                    


                $valorP="";
                if($categoriaP=='jpg' || $categoriaP=='png'){
                    $valorP="<img width='50' src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($portada)."'>";
                }

                if($categoriaP=='pdf'){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='../login/img/pdf.png'>";
                }

                if($categoriaP=='xls' || $categoriaP=='xlsm' ){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='../login/img/excel.png'>";
                }

                if($categoriaP=='doc' || $categoriaP=='docx'){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='../login/img/word.png'>";
                }
                if($categoriaP=='mp4'){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='../login/img/pelicula.png'>";
                }

                if($categoriaP=='mp3'){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='../login/img/musica.png'>";
                }

                if($valorP==''){
                    $valorP="<img  width='50' src='img/desconocido.png'>";
                }   
            }                                   
?>

var n = 0;
function contador() {
   
    var intervalo = setInterval(function agregarImg() {
        n += 1;

        const imagen = "<?= $valorP ?>"//Img en variable para enviar lo que desees
        const contenedor = document.getElementById("portada");
        contenedor.insertAdjacentHTML(
          "beforeend",
          ` ${imagen}  ` // Backticks para img variable

        );

        if (n == 1) {
      clearInterval(intervalo);
    }

      }, 1000)

    }

    contador();
    

      

    </script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2c36e9b7b1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```